# React Native Debug Menu does not open - Android CMD + M

Tags: react-native

React native debug menu does not work in Android.

Command 'RR' does work.
CMD + M does not work.

It was working previously. Keyboard input is enabled in AVD Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an obscure setting only available after opening the emulator.

Toggle `Send keyboard shortcuts to`: `Emulator Controls (default)`

I have no idea why this was so hard to find. Hopefully you reap the benefits of my stress and heartache.

I wish you the best Christmas in 2017 and that 2018 is great for you.

[image: Emulator Settings]