# React native developer menu won't show on Android Studio emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio-3.0, react-native-navigation

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.52.3

I am using Android Studio 3.1.2. Launched an emulator, and run `react-native run-android`. Everything built successfully. However, I couldn't get the developer menu shown on the emulator. It is supposed to be a simple `command + m` or `adb shell input keyevent 82`(according to facebook doc) for mac user, but I got this instead:

[image]

If I do `command + m` when the app is running, it has no response.

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator is a fresh extraction (and you have not changed the settings from default), you need to configure the emulator to send key commands to the program.

After you have opened the emulator, go to its settings, and ensure that `Send keyboard shortcuts` is set to `Send keyboard shortcuts to: Emulator Controls`.

Source: [React Native Debug Menu does not open - Android CMD + M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321228/react-native-debug-menu-does-not-open-android-cmd-m)

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18515

Comment: Didn't see this. I guess it is still a bug ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is what the official GitHub indicates. If you have a GitHub, I would file another bug request and possibly it can get more attention.

Comment: I will ask, though, why are you using version 52 not the more recent version 55?

Comment: I didn't think it'd make a difference. Maybe it's worth trying with v55. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, now upgraded to 55, still the same.

Comment: Do you experience the same functionality after completing the following steps: 1) restarting your computer and 2) creating a new sample RN project?