# Open Dev Menu or reload app without shaking React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have Oppo device, and i am not able to open dev menu (with shaking also) in react native app.

I have tried command `adb shell input keyevent 82` ([ref](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)) but it opens recent items.

Is there any other way to open dev menu without shaking and this command?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321228/react-native-debug-menu-does-not-open-android-cmd-m?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Did you notice, i have real device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Dev Menu or reload app without shaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515325/open-dev-menu-or-reload-app-without-shaking)

Answer (score 0):

When you start the service, a prompt will be printed in the terminal.

`"start": "react-native start",`

Press `d`

```
      Welcome to Metro!
Fast - Scalable - Integrated

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```